# Maximize nw.js window from protractor doesn't work

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, nw.js

I want to maximise the window from protractor. I am testing a **nw.js** app.

I added the below line in onPrepare statement in protractor-conf.js, but nothing worked

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

setSize also doesn't work

```
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(800, 600);
```

In all the cases I am getting the below error.

```
 var template = new Error(this.message);
             ^
UnknownError: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
```

This is the e2e configuration,

**protractor-conf.js**

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var nw = require('nw');

exports.config = {
    chromeDriver: './support/chromedriver',
    directConnect: true,
    specs: ['e2e/**/*.js'],
    rootElement: 'html',
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            binary: nw.findpath()
        }
    },

    onPrepare: function() {
        // By default, Protractor use data:text/html,<html></html> as resetUrl, but 
        // location.replace (see http://git.io/tvdSIQ) from the data: to the file: protocol is not allowed
        // (we'll get ‘not allowed local resource’ error), so we replace resetUrl with one
        // with the file: protocol (this particular one will open system's root folder)
        browser.resetUrl = 'file://';

        // This isn't required and used to avoid ‘Cannot extract package’ error showed
        // before Protractor have redirected node-webkit to resetUrl.

        browser.driver.get('file://' + path.resolve('app/index.html'));
    }
};
```

Is there a way to resolve this ?

I am testing this on Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you see the error if you don't try to change the browser window size? Is this reproducible in Firefox too? Thanks.

Comment: It works fine, if I don't try to change the size of the window. This is a nw.js app, so it can only be tested in nw.js (Formerly known as node-webkit)

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution for this issue? I encountered this issue recently.

Comment: @RongrongLuo I did not find a solution for this issue, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the arguments for chrome inside capabilities ?
http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

```
chromeOptions: {
    args: [
        '--start-maximized',
    ]
}
```